# Classbuilding with scss (double ampersand)

Tags: css, sass

I want to get the following selector `B__E.B__E--M` so that `B__E--M` only applies if the element also has the `B__E` class;

I have the following:

```
.B {
    &__E {
        // default color
        &--M {
            // Color i want
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the `--M` modifier should apply another color, but doesn't overwrite the default color from the `__E` element.

This is not allowed:

```
.B {
    &__E {
        // default color
    }
}

.B__E.B__E--M {
    // color i want
}
```

If nothing is possible, this would be my guess:

```
.B {
    &__E {
        // default color
        &.B__E--M {
            // Color i want
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the double ampersand selector.

```
.B {
    &__E {
        color:black;
        &#{&}--M{
          color:white;
        }
    }
}

/* // Outputs:
  .B__E {
    color: black;
  }
  .B__E.B__E--M {
    color: white;
  }
*/
```

Comment: Exactly! Didn't know that one ;)